# Two new lines instead of one

Tags: python

I banged my head as to why this code is inserting two new lines instead of one. Can someone help?

```
file=open('16052013')
for line in file:
    line=line.strip()
    splitLine=line.split("\t")
    strSentence=splitLine[2]
    caseId=splitLine[0]
    for word in strSentence.split():
        word=word.strip()
        print caseId,'\t',word
    print '\n'
```

Comment: change `print '\n'` to just `print`

Comment: `print` will auto new line. and if you do not want to new line, you can add a 'comma' after `print`. Just `print xxx,`

Comment: you should avoid the identifier "file" since it shadows a builtin: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=file#file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The print statement, unless the values passed to it end with a comma, always appends an extra newline.

Answer (score 4):

The `print` statement automatically appends a new line. You don't need to do a `print '\n'` again.

Also, it would be better if you used `with open('fileName') as f:` in your programs instead of `file = open('fileName')`: in that way the file is closed as soon as you exit from the scope of the `with` statement and you avoid to shadow the builtin name "file".

Comment: @SukritKalra you're welcome and don't worry, I spotted it quickly simply because I have done it, too (isn't experience acquired that way? :-) )